# Android WebRTC doesn't work on Different network - No Video

Tags: android, video, webrtc, stun, turn

I am trying to stream video from Raspberry Pi to android device via webrtc. I am using firebase (firestore) as signalling. I am able to run the setup while connected to same wifi but it fails when different networks are being used.

Device - RPI

Client 
1) Web client (hosted on firebase)
2) Android App

On same network (wifi) between device and clients, both clients are able to play video and audio.

But when device and client are on different network, web client is able to show video but Android App is not able to show video.

Signalling is working correctly and on device, camera and microphone are started and ice candidates are exchanged successfully. I also get remote stream added (onAddStream called) on android. But no video and audio is playing.

Android PeerConnectionClient

```
    class PeerConnectionClient(private val activity: MainActivity, private val fSignalling: FSignalling) {

    internal var isVideoRunning = false

    private val rootEglBase by lazy {
        EglBase.create()
    }

    private val peerConnectionFactory: PeerConnectionFactory by lazy {
        val initializationOptions = PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(activity).createInitializationOptions()
        PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(initializationOptions)

        val options = PeerConnectionFactory.Options()
        val defaultVideoEncoderFactory = DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(rootEglBase.eglBaseContext, true, true)
        val defaultVideoDecoderFactory = DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(rootEglBase.eglBaseContext)
        PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
                .setOptions(options)
                .setVideoEncoderFactory(defaultVideoEncoderFactory)
                .setVideoDecoderFactory(defaultVideoDecoderFactory)
                .createPeerConnectionFactory()
    }

    private val iceServersList = mutableListOf("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302")

    private var sdpConstraints: MediaConstraints? = null
    private var localAudioTrack: AudioTrack? = null

    private var localPeer: PeerConnection? = null

    private var gotUserMedia: Boolean = false
    private var peerIceServers: MutableList<PeerConnection.IceServer> = ArrayList()

    init {
        peerIceServers.add(PeerConnection.IceServer.builder(iceServersList).createIceServer())

        // activity.surface_view.release()
        activity.surface_view.init(rootEglBase.eglBaseContext, null)
        activity.surface_view.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true)

        createPeer()
    }

    private fun createPeer() {
        sdpConstraints = MediaConstraints()


        val audioconstraints = MediaConstraints()
        val audioSource = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioSource(audioconstraints)
        localAudioTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioTrack("101", audioSource)
        gotUserMedia = true

        activity.runOnUiThread {
            if (localAudioTrack != null) {
                createPeerConnection()
                // doCall()
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Creating the local peerconnection instance
     */
    private fun createPeerConnection() {
        val constraints = MediaConstraints()
        constraints.mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("offerToReceiveAudio", "true"))
        constraints.mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("offerToReceiveVideo", "true"))
        constraints.optional.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", "true"))

        val rtcConfig = PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(peerIceServers)
        // TCP candidates are only useful when connecting to a server that supports
        // ICE-TCP.
        rtcConfig.enableDtlsSrtp = true
        rtcConfig.enableRtpDataChannel = true
        // rtcConfig.tcpCandidatePolicy = PeerConnection.TcpCandidatePolicy.DISABLED
        // rtcConfig.bundlePolicy = PeerConnection.BundlePolicy.MAXBUNDLE
        // rtcConfig.rtcpMuxPolicy = PeerConnection.RtcpMuxPolicy.REQUIRE
        // rtcConfig.continualGatheringPolicy = PeerConnection.ContinualGatheringPolicy.GATHER_CONTINUALLY
        // Use ECDSA encryption.
        // rtcConfig.keyType = PeerConnection.KeyType.ECDSA
        localPeer = peerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(rtcConfig, constraints, object : PeerObserver {
            override fun onIceCandidate(p0: IceCandidate) {
                super.onIceCandidate(p0)
                onIceCandidateReceived(p0)
            }

            override fun onAddStream(p0: MediaStream) {
                activity.showToast("Received Remote stream")
                super.onAddStream(p0)
                gotRemoteStream(p0)
            }

        })

        addStreamToLocalPeer()
    }

    /**
     * Adding the stream to the localpeer
     */
    private fun addStreamToLocalPeer() {
        //creating local mediastream
        val stream = peerConnectionFactory.createLocalMediaStream("102")
        stream.addTrack(localAudioTrack)
        localPeer!!.addStream(stream)
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the app is initiator - We generate the offer and send it over through socket
     * to remote peer
     */
    /*private fun doCall() {
        localPeer!!.createOffer(object : mySdpObserver {
            override fun onCreateSuccess(p0: SessionDescription) {
                super.onCreateSuccess(p0)
                localPeer!!.setLocalDescription(object: mySdpObserver {}, p0)
                Log.d("onCreateSuccess", "SignallingClient emit ")
            }
        }, sdpConstraints)
    }*/

    private fun onIceCandidateReceived(iceCandidate: IceCandidate) {
        //we have received ice candidate. We can set it to the other peer.
        if (localPeer == null) {
            return
        }

        val message = JSONObject()
        message.put("type", "candidate")
        message.put("label", iceCandidate.sdpMLineIndex)
        message.put("id", iceCandidate.sdpMid)
        message.put("candidate", iceCandidate.serverUrl)

        fSignalling.doSignalingSend(message.toString())
    }

    private fun gotRemoteStream(stream: MediaStream) {
        isVideoRunning = true
        //we have remote video stream. add to the renderer.
        val videoTrack = stream.videoTracks[0]
        videoTrack.setEnabled(true)
        activity.runOnUiThread {
            try {
                // val remoteRenderer = VideoRenderer(surface_view)
                activity.surface_view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                // videoTrack.addRenderer(remoteRenderer)
                videoTrack.addSink(activity.surface_view)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    fun onReceivePeerMessage(data: JSONObject) {
        if (data.getString("type") == "offer") {
            // val sdpReturned = SdpUtils.forceChosenVideoCodec(data.getString("sdp"), "H264")
            val sdpReturned = data.getString("sdp")
            // data.remove("sdp")
            // data.put("sdp", sdpReturned)

            val sessionDescription = SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.OFFER, sdpReturned)

            localPeer?.setRemoteDescription(object: mySdpObserver { }, sessionDescription)

            localPeer?.createAnswer(object : mySdpObserver {
                override fun onCreateSuccess(p0: SessionDescription) {
                    super.onCreateSuccess(p0)
                    localPeer!!.setLocalDescription( object : mySdpObserver {}, p0)

                    val description = JSONObject()
                    description.put("type", p0.type.canonicalForm())
                    description.put("sdp", p0.description)

                    this@PeerConnectionClient.fSignalling.doSignalingSend(description.toString())
                }

                override fun onCreateFailure(p0: String) {
                    super.onCreateFailure(p0)
                    activity.showToast("Failed to create answer")
                }

            }, MediaConstraints())

        } else if (data.getString("type") == "candidate") {
            val iceCandidates = IceCandidate(data.getString("id"), data.getInt("label"), data.getString("candidate"))
            localPeer?.addIceCandidate(iceCandidates)
        }
    }

    internal fun close() {
        isVideoRunning = false
        localPeer?.close()
        localPeer = null
    }
 }
```

I am under the impression that if web client is able to display video on different network (mobile hotspot), android client on same internet used by web client should be able to display video as well. Is it wrong? 
Why won't android display video (onAddStream is called)

Is it required to use Turn server? My assumption again is the if web client works, so should android. The service i am using on RPI do not have support for turn server.

Additional info: 
Device is behind double natted ISP (i guess) (but since web client can connect, it won't be an issue i guess).

Comment: Hii there,I am not getting audio candidate from one peer.can u please provide me more details what u do to get video candidates on both peers?

Comment: @richashah  request and add to peer before sending answer or request.

Comment: what's the use of enableRtpDataChannel in your code?

Comment: @richashah webrtc have data channels to exchange data like messages or files etc

Comment: i am also creating same type of app but it works only when they are on same network not working on different network can help with some kind of webrtc level code please?

Comment: i am creating app for android to android only so

Comment: @gulabpatel how did you solve your problem ? Am facing same issue. I posted a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72806611/webrtc-does-not-work-on-different-network-cellular-data

Comment: @John  infact i have changed my implementation and I have used peerJs for this. PeerJs is easy to set up and use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to the issue

I was using

```
private fun onIceCandidateReceived(iceCandidate: IceCandidate) {
    //we have received ice candidate. We can set it to the other peer.
    if (localPeer == null) {
        return
    }

    val message = JSONObject()
    message.put("type", "candidate")
    message.put("label", iceCandidate.sdpMLineIndex)
    message.put("id", iceCandidate.sdpMid)
    message.put("candidate", iceCandidate.serverUrl)

    fSignalling.doSignalingSend(message.toString())
}
```

Instead was required to use

```
message.put("candidate", iceCandidate.sdp) // iceCandidate.serverUrl)
```

Comment: I have been signalling the correct parameters, but still no luck (I am using Flutter).
(P.S.: I am in the exact same scenario as the question says)