# WebRTC does not work on different network/cellular data

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am facing a problem. I can connect by webrtc in local network (using wifi), but not being able to connect to different netowrk. How can I solve this problem?

```
new RTCPeerConnection({
    iceServers: [
      { urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" },
      { urls: "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302" },
      { urls: "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302" },
      { urls: "stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302" },
      {
        url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
        credential: 'muazkh',
        username: 'webrtc@live.com'
      }
    ]
  });
```

Caller -- (Cellular network) log

```
    *** Negotiation needed

Track added - true

---> Creating offer

---> Setting local description to the offer

*** WebRTC signaling state changed to: have-local-offer

---> Sending the offer to the remote peer

{"type":"offer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 613095391791482847 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0\r\na=extmap-allow-mixed\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS Xfgp8d5z5kDjOpdAhdQ71GA5CQchvV6f1P29\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 9 0 8 105 13 110 113 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:yr8E\r\na=ice-pwd:aY0ptyV4+qlcN3O5i8l9ApdA\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 9B:51:75:EA:97:F5:0C:46:2F:54:3F:4B:55:34:6A:A0:AE:CB:F5:2A:AD:D3:EB:23:5F:2B:AA:F3:54:89:7C:D8\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:0\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id\r\na=extmap:6 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=msid:Xfgp8d5z5kDjOpdAhdQ71GA5CQchvV6f1P29 574ebf18-2253-4c92-9e22-c799159399c7\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:105 CN/16000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000\r\na=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\na=ssrc:954464282 cname:u4QAtLPWh6uHA7eN\r\na=ssrc:954464282 msid:Xfgp8d5z5kDjOpdAhdQ71GA5CQchvV6f1P29 574ebf18-2253-4c92-9e22-c799159399c7\r\na=ssrc:954464282 mslabel:Xfgp8d5z5kDjOpdAhdQ71GA5CQchvV6f1P29\r\na=ssrc:954464282 label:574ebf18-2253-4c92-9e22-c799159399c7\r\n"}

*** ICE gathering state changed to: gathering

*** Outgoing ICE candidate: candidate:3988473628 1 udp 2122260223 10.94.236.243 59747 typ host generation 0 ufrag yr8E network-id 1 network-cost 10

*** Outgoing ICE candidate: candidate:2738404332 1 tcp 1518280447 10.94.236.243 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag yr8E network-id 1 network-cost 10

*** Outgoing ICE candidate: candidate:1827881384 1 udp 1686052607 103.253.46.151 11381 typ srflx raddr 10.94.236.243 rport 59747 generation 0 ufrag yr8E network-id 1 network-cost 10

*** Call recipient has accepted our call

*** Adding received ICE candidate: {"candidate":"candidate:3351850224 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.0.5 45822 typ host generation 0 ufrag ebh0 network-id 1 network-cost 10","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0}

*** WebRTC signaling state changed to: stable

***
```

> ICE connection state changed to checking

```
*** Adding received ICE candidate: {"candidate":"candidate:2303381504 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.0.5 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag ebh0 network-id 1 network-cost 10","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0}

*** Adding received ICE candidate: {"candidate":"candidate:1855365925 1 udp 1686052607 103.138.125.193 45822 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.5 rport 45822 generation 0 ufrag ebh0 network-id 1 network-cost 10","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0}

*** ICE connection state changed to disconnected

Disonnected

*** ICE gathering state changed to: complete
```

Receiver Log--- (Wifi/broadband connection)

```
Received video chat offer from cd625e27-f1e8-40f4-9cb2-0d415bccaf0b

- Setting remote description

*** WebRTC signaling state changed to: have-remote-offer

Track added - true

---> Creating and sending answer to caller

*** WebRTC signaling state changed to: stable

{"type":"answer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 1805969134806418443 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0\r\na=extmap-allow-mixed\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS fX8AVqBizpVv9FtfBPN3jn06D5G0TDxwzbve\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 9 0 8 105 13 110 113 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:ebh0\r\na=ice-pwd:IC096hRjgd0/J6riuOr5/4pL\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 EB:BD:EA:35:C9:C7:7A:D6:AE:95:1B:A5:52:E8:D7:62:74:72:89:70:08:09:88:8E:D5:B4:91:03:99:7E:9B:0A\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:0\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=msid:fX8AVqBizpVv9FtfBPN3jn06D5G0TDxwzbve 755ea3c3-a9cf-4ed3-b2e1-ca318c57860b\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:105 CN/16000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000\r\na=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\na=ssrc:678356208 cname:fq1NgjQWtrq1/SLi\r\n"}

*** ICE gathering state changed to: gathering

*** Outgoing ICE candidate: candidate:3351850224 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.0.5 45822 typ host generation 0 ufrag ebh0 network-id 1 network-cost 10

*** Outgoing ICE candidate: candidate:2303381504 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.0.5 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag ebh0 network-id 1 network-cost 10

*** Outgoing ICE candidate: candidate:1855365925 1 udp 1686052607 103.138.125.193 45822 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.5 rport 45822 generation 0 ufrag ebh0 network-id 1 network-cost 10

*** ICE gathering state changed to: complete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the logs you provided I can tell your turn server is not accessible as there are no `relay` candidates on both ends.

The easiest way to check it is via [trickle ice](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) page. It might be that you use a wrong port, made a typo in credentials or that the server is not responding.

Comment: the turn server credentials used were changed about 10 years ago

Comment: webrtc might not work without turn depending on the network setup, so i suggest you adding one. For testing you might use a free one provided after registering on https://xirsys.com/

Comment: I recommend using the Openrelayproject's free TURN servers provided by them. Refer to: https://dev.to/aprogrammer22/list-of-free-stun-and-turn-servers-open-relay-project-3a70